# Как удалить все нечисловые и не буквенные символы, идущие в начале строки до первой буквы или цифры

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка

$str = "=~*_Размер 3 * 2";

Надо удалить все символы, которые идут в начале строки до первой встреченной в строке буквы (русской или латинской) или цифры.
То есть из данной строки на выходе я хочу получить

Размер 3 * 2

Пробовал что-то типа такого

```
$str = preg_replace("/([^a-zA-Z0-9А-Яа-я]+?)[a-zA-Z0-9А-Яа-я]/u", "", $str);
```

но на выходе получается

азмер

Comment: `/^[^\p{L}\p{N}]+/u`  [Песочница](https://regex101.com/r/PcY1Sc/1)

Comment: Спасибо, это то что надо.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте

```php
<?php

$str = "=~*_Размер 3 * 2";
echo preg_replace('/^[^\p{L}\d]+/u', '', $str);
```

См. [пример кода на PHP](https://3v4l.org/sQ10O).

**Подробности**

- `^` - начало строки
- `[^` - начало отрицающего символьного класса, находит все символы, отличные от

  - `\p{L}` - любой буквы
  - `\d` - цифры
- `]+` - один и более раз

См. [пример работы выражения](https://regex101.com/r/zVGOPH/1).

Comment: Слева и справа: `preg_replace('/^[^\p{L}\p{N}]+|\s*[^\p{L}\p{N}]+$/u', '', $str);`

Comment: @ArthurShlain Только ``\s*`` лишний.